# Map color change on hover?

Tags: html, css, canvas, coordinates

*I'm not sure which method it is the best one.* 
The point is, creating an interactive map I know these ways to make it work:

```
<map id="mapdk" name="mapdk">
<area shape="poly" coords="7,230,12,230,14,232,17,233,20,230,22,231,25,234,29,235,31,231,33,228,39,228,43,228,46,232,50,232,51,225,56,223,60,222,62,223,61,227,64,229,68,228,71,225,74,221,77,217,80,215,82,215,84,217,87,218,91,219,92,222,94,225,94,227,95,230,97,230,99,232,100,234,103,234,105,234,105,237,105,239,108,239,109,240,109,243,105,245,104,244,105,247,108,246,110,246,114,246,117,247,121,247,124,247,127,247,130,246,134,244,133,241,136,240,134,238,132,236,135,233,134,230,130,230,126,230,122,229,124,226,126,226,129,225,133,224,136,224,139,224,140,225,141,227,144,228,145,224,146,221,148,217,148,212,148,208,148,202,147,195,146,188,149,184,152,182,154,179,156,176,159,173,161,174,162,176,162,179,161,184,158,183,157,183,154,185,155,187,156,189,159,188,162,186,165,187,169,182,172,182,174,182,175,184,173,186,175,189,177,191,179,187,179,183,185,177,188,171,191,164,193,156,191,151,187,147,184,143,178,144,173,145,168,146,160,145,154,143,151,140,150,138,147,143,146,148,142,151,136,154,153,133,153,129,153,125,150,119,147,112,147,106,147,101,148,94,152,87,153,81,154,76,157,69,159,64,163,62,164,55,161,45,163,40,165,35,159,29,156,22,156,17,157,12,159,8,162,5,166,2,169,0,161,1,156,5,152,8,148,12,144,15,140,17,134,19,130,18,126,19,121,22,117,30,100,59,94,64,82,71,69,72,64,71,60,72,54,76,49,77,40,77,35,78,27,87,23,93,17,102,14,111,13,117,16,117,17,121,20,126,24,129,28,135,31,139,32,140,35,138,38,135,38,134,38,131,37,130,35,128,33,127,30,126,30,121,29,116,32,113,38,109,39,111,41,112,36,114,35,116,34,121,35,123,38,128,41,129,43,128,45,127,49,126,50,123,53,118,54,115" href="#" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="34,213" href="#" /></map>
```

also using something like this:

```
#mapdk {
 list-style: none;
 background: url(images/mapdk.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 580px;
 height: 268px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#mapdk:hover {
 background: url(images/mapdk_red.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

And at last using `canvas`

But which one it is the most `optimal` to make a task like this.

**thanks** in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by optimal. If you are creating a map, I'd say `map` is probably the best way to go. Why using something else when there is an element thought for that purpose?

Now, if you have some special functionality (animations or graphs for example) that can't be done using `map`, you should consider the `canvas` instead.

For purposes of the `:hover`, they are both the same. I wouldn't use hover for something that is not a `button`, though (I'd use JS) but since you are using **html5** it shouldn't really be a problem (you are not supporting older browsers anyway).